# Linearizable reductive group action.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $k$ be a 0 characteristic field, and $G$ a reductive group in $GA_2(k)$ (the group of automorphisms of k[x,y] as k-algebra). How is it possible to deduce that $G$ is conjugated to a subgroup of $GL_2(k)$ ?

Comment: Could you clarify what $GA_{2}(k)$ is please? I haven't seen the notation before.

Comment: $GA_2(k)$ is the group of automorphisms of $k[x,y]$ as $k$-algebra.